# How to return blank or null record when using STUFF and XML PATH on SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, for-xml-path, stuff

I am using STUFF and XML PATH as it is obligatory that I use SQL Server 2016. I have been working on this query and I cannot figure out how to return null or blank record when using STUFF and XML PATH. Below is the snippet of the query.

```
SELECT 
    Names = STUFF((SELECT '; ' + CONCAT(t3.FirstName, ' ', t3.LastName)
                   FROM table1 t1
                   LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t0.columnID = t2.columnID
                   LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.columnID = t3.columnID
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,''),
```

The issue is that when there is no lastname/firstname, this query returns the separators '; ;' but I need it to return blank value if there is no lastname / firstname.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What you want to accomplish is rather unclear.

Comment: Just use a `CASE` so instead of `SELECT '; ' + CONCAT(t3.FirstName, ' ', t3.LastName)` do `SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(t3.FirstName, '') = '' AND ISNULL(t3.LastName, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE  '; ' + CONCAT(t3.FirstName, ' ', t3.LastName) END`

Comment: `'; ;'`? So you're running with `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF`? Be aware that the `OFF` setting is deprecated, and has been for many years, and will be effectively removed in a future version of SQL Server. Consider switching code that uses `ISNULL` and `NULLIF` constructs instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `WHERE`:

```
WHERE t3.FirstName IS NOT NULL OR t3.LastName IS NOT NULL
```

In this case, you probably also want to deal with one of them being null and getting an extra space:

```
SELECT '; ' + CASE
    WHEN t3.FirstName IS NOT NULL AND t3.LastName IS NULL THEN t3.FirstName
    WHEN t3.LastName IS NOT NULL AND t3.FirstName IS NULL THEN t3.LastName
    ELSE CONCAT(t3.FirstName, ' ', t3.LastName) END
```

Also, because your separator is two characters long, you need to change the `STUFF` parameters:
`FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2,'')`